# Custom Translation Animation not working correctly

Tags: java, android, animation

I am attempting to animate a part of an android app, unfortunately I can not get my animation to work correctly.

The following xml file works correctly, but it has an absolute reference rather than a relative one.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<objectAnimator xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
        android:propertyName="x" 
        android:valueType="floatType"
        android:valueTo="0" 
        android:valueFrom="100"
        android:duration="800"
/>
```

When I try a a relative reference, like the following, the animation is not correct. It produces the correct screen, but the fragment just appears, rather than sliding in from the left.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<objectAnimator xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:propertyName="translationX" 
    android:fromXDelta="100%"
    android:toXDelta="0%"
    android:duration="500"/>
```

Does anyone have the solution to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reverse your fromXdelta and toxDelta values. You are applying the 100% change at the start of the animation and 0% at the end.

From: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/TranslateAnimation.html

fromXValue  Change in X coordinate to apply at the start of the animation.

toXValue    Change in X coordinate to apply at the end of the animation.